# Make the language of First Order Logic uncountable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computability, formal-languages

The question is in regards to The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem and the question asks to give a set of sentences that is only true in an uncountable domain. My teacher told me to solve this by "relaxing" the conditions on the language of first order logic so that it is uncountable.

Because the question asks to give a set of sentences in an uncountable **domain** this leads me to believe that I should try to make either the set of countably infinite constants and/or countably infinite variables uncountable, in the language, but i'm stuck on how to do this and apply it so there's sentences that are only true in this uncountable domain. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add an uncountable set of new constants : $\{ c_r \}_{r \in \mathbb R}$

Comment: I suspect the idea is to use not only an uncountable collection of constants, but also an uncountable set of axioms involving those constants.

Comment: And consider the set of sentences $\{\, \lnot(c_r=c_s} \, :\, r, s\in R, \, r\ne s\,\} $

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA AH this sounds like it will work, im just having trouble thinking of a set of sentences that is only true with these constants?

Comment: @Berci I'm having trouble reading your comment, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: It might be interesting to note that the first-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces is naturally uncountable (it has uncountably many unary function symbols for "scalar multiples", one for each scalar in $\mathbb{R}$), and any nontrivial $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is also an uncountable domain.